# FindWindowByClassNameAndRegex issue with special characters

Tags: c#, regex, pinvoke

For our software testing we have a test that lets us check to see if certain windows are open using the FindWindowByClassNameAndRegex P/Invoke call. The issue we're getting is when we have windows open with more than a certain number of special characters we always get IntPtr.Zero as a return. Are there any known issues with this? Here's some of the code we use to find the window: (in this case it's for a firefox window)

`Regex windowTitleRegex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(fullWindowTitle).Replace("\?", "."), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
                    curWindowHandle = NativeMethods.FindWindowByClassNameAndRegex("MozillaUIWindowClass", windowTitleRegex);`

Where the title of the window is `` ~`!@#$%^&*()_-+={[}]|:;'<,>.?/\"àëÉùÙâÏûâÏûÊÛçîÀË«éïÂÎ»œÇÔêôÈŒ\ ``
(There's no actual line break it's just a formatting thing)

Comment: What is `FindWindowByClassNameAndRegex`?

Comment: @Tergiver : It's a native function call in Windows that will return a window handle to a window that matches the Window class name and the given regular expression.

Comment: There may be some encoding issues.

Comment: A Google search on FindWindowByClassNameAndRegex turns up nothing except this question. What is it really?

Comment: @Tergiver It goes through all the windows and uses Regex.isMatch() to check the window titles of all windows that are currently open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Windows API function by that name.  I'm guessing you've found some DLL that exports this function.  Odds are always good that the regex this DLL uses is of some kind that doesn't quite match the syntax that .NET's Regex class uses.  There are a lot of dialects.

Best thing to do is to pinvoke EnumWindows().  You can use your own Regex in the callback to filter, GetClassName() gets you the window class name.  If you already know the window name then just use FindWindow().

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but yeah it' something written in our libraries (someone placed it in our NativeMethods incorrectly) it uses GetTopLevelwindows and GetClassName. It is written in C# so I don't see the problem with the matching since we get the window title from firefox by using javascript.

Comment: Turns out there was a typo buried in the code that was escaping characters that shouldn't be escaped. Thanks for the suggestion though.